# MSCharts PixelPositionToValue doesn't seem to work for logarithmic x-axis

Tags: c#, .net, forms, charts, mschart

I am using MSCharts, and have set the x-axis IsLogarithmic to true.  The first problem I had was that the chart crashed when it was first displayed.

I found answers at:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/MSWinWebChart/thread/33288389-0A46-4C01-8E36-761B7BE96F0D

and

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/MSWinWebChart/thread/056aa11f-658c-48fa-9768-cde912cd2975

So I don't set isLogarithmic at design time, I do it at runtime when I have a series with:

- X-values specified with no x values <= 0
- Series.IsXValueIndexed = false
- AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = false

However, I have a problem when trying to drag some points on the graph.  The MS example code for dragging points uses the PixelPositionToValue function in the MouseMove event handler.  However, when I try this with the log axis I have to convert the value myself back to linear with code like:

```
int GetXValue(MouseEventArgs e, Axis axis)
{
 return axis.IsLogarithmic ?
   Math.Pow(axis.LogarithmBase, axis.PixelPositionToValue(e.X)) :
   axis.PixelPositionToValue(e.X)
}
```

I don't think I should really have to do this, and worse, sometimes PixelPositionToValue does seem to convert the value to linear for me, so the function above gives inconsistent results.

I noticed that the documentation for PixelPositionToValue says "Converts an absolute pixel position along an axis to an axis value. **This method only works in paint events**.", even though the MS example code for dragging points uses it in the Chart1_MouseMove event handler.

So, for probably very illogical reasons I tried calling `Chart1.Refresh()` after plotting my points (rather than `Chart1.Invalidate()`) and the inconsistent behaviour seems to have gone away.

My question is, has anyone tried a similar thing and found a proper way to get PixelPositionToValue to work consistently for a logarithmic x-axis, or found another workaround that doesn't require manually converting the point to linear and calling `Chart1.Refresh()`?

Comment: The example has been removed.  You need to take this comment seriously, the axis mapping is done lazily.  Not until it is painted does it need to be nailed down.  It probably works after the first paint but you still risk getting a stale value since painting is a low priority task.  Only GetPosition() is truly safe.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for this - that gave me an impetus to dig a bit further on the net and I found a proper fix for the inconsistent calculation method (although I would still prefer not to have to have different code for log and linear axes).  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following articles:

http://support2.dundas.com/newsletter/04-07/newsletter.htm

http://support2.dundas.com/forum/tm.aspx?m=2786

http://support2.dundas.com/forum/tm.aspx?m=4616&mpage=1&key=ሴ

http://support2.dundas.com/forum/printable.aspx?m=3636

These indicate that for PixelPositionToValue to work outside of a paint event you need to call ReCalc() on the Chart area.  ReCalc() doesn't exist on my version of MSChart, but there is a function RecalculateAxesScale() (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/da45b7df-8d2f-4598-b4ad-47964eb1505c/), and calling this seems to fix the inconsistent behaviour.

Unfortunately I still need to convert the value to linear if the axis is logarithmic, but at least the behaviour is predictable now.

Comment: Although this question seems pretty dead, it's actually the top result when I google "PixelPositionToValue logarithmic"
This Q/A pair has been super useful - good work dominic!